# Do a MongoDB update with Spring XD & Spring Integration

Tags: mongodb, spring-integration, spring-xd

I'm trying to read a file with Spring XD (source), modify data (processor) and save it in Mongo (sink). I've used the default MongoDB sink which do a save and expect a Spring Data Mongo entity.
But I'd like to do an update with upsert. How can I do ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The mongo outbound adapter uses MongoTemplate.save() which is already an upsert according to [the javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#save-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Yes but when I try this, my json contains **$inc** and **$set** to handle insert/update. And it fail because **$inc** is not authorized...

Comment: So which can of object can I use to save into mongo? (I don't use Spring Data, so I've JSON or DBObject) And I need to do upsert with $inc & $set...

Answer (score 0):

If you provide your own ObjectId for the same object it will update. You can for example do this during your processor.